# Wordpress menu changes is not saving

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello I am facing an issue with my wordpress.no change in menu is being saved. when I edit or change position of any menu and click save, the page just keep loading. but no result. I deactivated all the plugins and changed theme too but situation remain same. but when I tried from mobile it works in chrome but not in mozilla. please give a solution if possible.

Thanks

Comment: press `ctrl+f5` for a hard refresh in your browser. Purge all cache if is there any caching plugin is active.

Comment: tried but not working.